# Nvidia optimus - Howto configure xserver on dual screen?

Tags: server, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, xserver

I have notebook with nvidia optimus technology. I have installed bumblebee and everything seems to work fine. The problem is that when I connected a second monitor to my notebook after login, it works well, but when I start the notebook with the monitor connected, then Xserver is not able to start. How to configure xserver to make it work?

This is my hardware config:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3040 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+1440+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 214mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1440x900       59.9 
   1360x768       59.8     60.0 
   1152x864       60.0 
   1024x768       60.0 
   800x600        60.3     56.2 
   640x480        59.9 
VGA2 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 256mm
   1440x900       59.9*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0 
   1152x864       75.0 
   1280x720       75.0     60.0 
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0 
   832x624        74.6 
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2 
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0 
   720x400        70.1 
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

edit: Here is my Horg.log

```
 [    15.921] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan  7 23:00:34 2012
[    15.921] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    15.921] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    15.921] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    15.921] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    15.921] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    15.921] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    15.921] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[    15.921] (**) |   |-->Device "Default Device"
[    15.921] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    15.921] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    15.921] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    15.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    15.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    15.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    15.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    15.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    15.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.921] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[    15.921] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    15.921] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    15.921] (II) Loader magic: 0x7e0220
[    15.921] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    15.921]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    15.921]    X.Org Video Driver: 10.0
[    15.921]    X.Org XInput driver : 12.3
[    15.921]    X.Org Server Extension : 5.0
```

My xorg.conf is almost empty:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Device"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection
```

Howto configure Xorg to make it works?

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for errors?